# Optimizing a filter on a Redis Cache

Tags: python, caching, redis

Let's say I have users, and users have events which consist of data and a datetime stamp.

If I wanted to have a cache of all the user's recent items, and filter the cache on the datetime stamp such that it's only events after a given time, is there a technique in place for this pattern?

Very generally speaking, I want a general purpose cache of the last 100 events by each user, and then filter these last 100 events on reference to the cache.

I'm thinking something like:

```
r = redis.Redis()
r.set('a', {'01-01-17': 10, '01-02-17': 20, '01-03-17': 30})
{k:v for k,v in eval(r.get('a')).iteritems() if k >= '01-01-02'}
```

this seems like it'd work but it would be nice to know what the standard approach would be.

Comment: I think zadd and zrangebyscore are going to be helpful

Comment: Definitely - you're in the right direction, keep plowing.

Comment: I probably would have accepted that as the answer!